# Linq2Sql: How to recreate a Union Select

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I would like to recreate the following in Linq2Sql

```
SqlStr = "SELECT RefNo, Title, Allocation, GenralMenu, AdminMenu, Redundant 
FROM Menus UNION SELECT 0,  '', '', 0, 0, 0 ORDER BY Title"
```

Unfortunately my attempts have not been fruitful. Is there a way of doing this? 
Or do I need to

- select records from Menus
- insert 'my union" record into the extracted list
- sort list by title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have solved my issue as follows

```
Dim dc As New DiaryDataContext
Dim menuList = (From m In dc.Menus
                Select m)

Dim dl As List(Of Menu)
dl = menuList.ToList
dl.Insert(0, New Menu With{.RefNo = 0,
                           .Title = "",
                           .Value = "",
                           .GeneralMenu = False,
                           .AdminMenu = False,
                           .Redundant = False})
gv_Menus.DataSource = dl
gv_Menus.DataBind()
```

A bit longer than the original SQL but works....

Answer (score -1):

**You need to use Insert/Select**
*Syntax example :*

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT Table2.column1  AS column1, Table2.column2 AS column2
from table2
WHERE Table2.column3 > 100
```

---

Linq2Sql

```
context
  .Table1
  .InsertAllOnSubmit(
    context
      .Table2
      .Where( ... )
      .Select(b => new A { ... })
  );
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused with your answer. The above is standard SQL, not Linq2Sql. Basically I need to select some records but within that selection I need to have an extra record with 0/blank values. The result is bound to a datagrid and on binding the 0 row will become a new record row. It all works using the above sql but I have been asked to change all db connections to used Sql2Linq. Thanks

Comment: Forgive me, but your code is inserting a series of values from Table2 into Table1. I don't want to have to create a new table in the DB each time the page this code is used on is opened up. I was hoping that I could use Linq2Sql to pull out of the DB all the records from Menu table and add to it an extra record that the grid would recognise as a 'NEW' row base on the value in the first column. I was hoping that Linq2Sql could do this in one command as the SqlStr I supplied does. It looks like I will need to follow my second option of select to List(Of T) and then Insert my new item into List.